# lme on panel data with 2 indexing variables in R?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I have never worked with longitudinal data before and I'm not sure how to approach modelling the data I have. The dataset looks like this:

```
ID, year, score1, score2, score3
1, 1, 90, 89, 91
1, 2, 78, 89, 88
1, 3, 92, 72, 93
1, 4, 69, 98, 89
2, 1, 86, 95, 90
2, 2, 73, 92, 78
3, 1, 82, 94, 87
3, 2, 85, 87, 98
3, 3, 91, 89, 89
```

i.e. the data is unbalanced (different number of years for each `ID`). The `year` variable indicates the the n-th year that the specific `ID` was observed.

I want to create a linear effects model on `score1` as a function of `score2 + score3` and indexing by the variables `ID` and `year`.

This is how I approached the code using the package `lme4`:

```
lmer(score1 ~ (score2 + score3 | ID/year), data=data)
```

I'm unsure how to create a lme model which indexes by both `ID` and `year` is this possible to do in R?

Comment: What do you mean "indexes by both ID and year". Also your model specifies year as nested within ID however they are not nested according to the description. Finally, what is the relation between score1, score2 and score3 ?

Comment: @RobertLong by "indexes by both ID and year" I mean that the model accounts for the fact that we're working with panel-data where we have a list of `ID`'s and for each ID we have several `year` observations. 

In terms of my model specifying year as nested within ID, this is probably why I need some help with the model as I'm unsure how to model the data correctly.

Finally, score1 score2 and score3 are arbitrary variable names I assigned for this example. In the dataset, they represent scores/ratings that relate to the ID